# How To Reload A iframe Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I've created a basic browser within a browser window using an iframe:

The purpose is to allow mouse-over styling of elements using jquery ie/ highlight all links red etc... change font etc..

I've created two files:

**browser.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <style>

        #netframe {
            float:right; 
            height: 100%; 
            width: 80%;
        }

        #sidebar {
            float:left; 
            height: 100%; 
            width: 20%;
        }

        </style>



    </head>
    <body>


    <div id="container">

        <div id="sidebar">

    Enter A URL:
            <input type="text" name="url" id="url">
            <input type="button" value="load" id="load">

            <br><br>    


        </div>

        <div id="netframe">
            <iframe height="100%" width="100%" class="netframe" src="pullsite.php" id="main_frame"></iframe>
        </div>

    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

And **pullsite.php**

```
<html>

<head>

    <title></title>

    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <style>
        .highlight { 
            outline-color: -moz-use-text-color !important;
            outline-style: dashed !important;
            outline-width: 2px !important;
        }
    </style>    

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



</head>

    <body>

    <div id="contents">           

    <?php echo file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=iw'); ?>

    </div>

        <script>

        $("#contents").contents().find("a").addClass("highlight");

        </script>


    </body>


</html>
```

Can someone please help with the jquery code I could use allow a user to enter a new url in the input field and reload the iframe.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of a HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="url" id="url"/>
<input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Go!"/>
<iframe id="miniBrowser"></iframe>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#go').on('click', function() {
  $('#miniBrowser').attr('src', $('#url').val());
});
```

Comment: Sorry this solution doesn't appear to work - at least not in FireFox 3.5.11 - any other ideas?!

Comment: Nevermind all working now! Wasn't loading jquery on the page properly first... The code works great - Thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain but try

```
$('#main_frame').attr('src','http://www.google.co.uk');
```

I can't test this at the minute but changing the src attribute on the iframe should cause a reload based on the new value.

This could be achieved from a url in a textbox by using

```
$('#load').click(function(){
    $('#main_frame').attr('src',$('#url').val());
});
```

Comment: Same supposition in my answer, and that's what I found on Google, too.